# JS Canvas - Filling a bean-shaped polygon

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, polygon

I have a problem with JS canvas `ctx.fill()` filling outside of my polygonal shape.

Here's how my code works :

```
ctx.beginPath()
// Here are for loops that draws a the closed shape using
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
```

Here are the for loops:

```
var sx1, sy1, ex1, ey1, sx2, sy2, ex2, ey2;
for(var i = 0; i < n; i += Math.floor(n/steps)){
 var radius = Math.exp(-2*i/n)*rmax+rmin;
 radius += frequencyData[i]/255*(n-i + 200)/n*50;
 var angle = -Math.PI/2 - i/n*2*Math.PI;
 var x = radius*Math.cos(angle) + w/2+rmin/2;
 var y = radius*Math.sin(angle) + (h-110)/2+rmin/2 + analyser_offset;

 if (i == 0) {
   gctx.moveTo(x,y);
   sx1 = x;
   sy1 = y;
 }else if (i == n-1){
   ex1 = x;
   ey1 = y;
 }else{
   gctx.lineTo(x,y);
 }

 spd += frequencyData[i];
}
for(var i = 0; i < n; i += Math.floor(n/steps)){
 var radius = Math.exp(-2*i/n)*rmax+rmin;
 radius -= frequencyData[i]/255*(n-i + 200)/n*50;
 var angle = -Math.PI/2 - i/n*2*Math.PI;
 var x = radius*Math.cos(angle) + w/2+rmin/2;
 var y = radius*Math.sin(angle) + (h-110)/2+rmin/2 + analyser_offset;

 if (i == 0) {
   gctx.moveTo(x,y);
 }else if (i == 20){
   sx2 = x;
   sy2 = y;
 }else if (i == n-1){
   ex2 = x;
   ey2 = y;
 } else {
   gctx.lineTo(x,y);
 }
}
gctx.moveTo(sx1, sy1);
gctx.lineTo(sx2, sy2);
gctx.moveTo(ex1, ey1);
gctx.lineTo(ex2, ey2);
```

So the first for loop draws the outter side of the shape, the second for loop draws the inner side. And then the `sx1, sy1, ex1, ey1, sx2, sy2, ex2, ey2` variables are here to ensure that in the last 4 lines, it closes the shape (by adding vertical line between the outter and inner lines). Maybe this problem happens because I draw the lines in an unusual order? (like drawing a rectangle by starting with 2 horizontal lines and then adding 2 vertical ones)
Here's what I get after the `fill()` :

[image: This is what I get]

And this is what I would like to have:

[image: This is what I need]

So could you guide me on how I'm supposed to achieve this?

Comment: Can you include the for loop?

Comment: @bugs sure, I just did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed it by making the second loop go in the reverse order like this: `for (var i = n-1; i >= 0; i -= Math.floor(n/steps))` so it draws the polygon in a more usual order and that works! I don't even need to close it using the last 4 lines which was what I wanted so that's great!